# c++ OS independent(windows &linux) open-source random number generators libraries?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, encryption, random

OS independent(windows &linux) open-source random number generators libraries ? (c++)

Comment: Why is std::rand insufficient? Not fast enough? Not secure enough? Or do you want a more comfortable API?

Comment: I want a more comfortable api, a more advanced thing. Like boost as the next answer suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) has [a lot of random number generator algorithms](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-number-generator-algorithms.html) implemented.

3rd party libraries aside, C++11 has [a couple of them as well](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). If you have access to a suitable C++11 environment and these suit your needs, use this.

Answer (score 7):

[Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

cstdlib provides random number generation ...